# Bootstrap modal does not show up from code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap, code-behind

It should be easy but it doesn't work. I searched and found an example on the internet and use Visual Studio 2013. The div is only in the Form and everyting is correct installed and bootstrap items from the form work fine.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "none", "$('#ModalZK');", True)


End Sub
```

The div is like the bootstrap example and starts with

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalZK" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only"></span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel4" style="text-align:center ">Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('#ModalZK');` isn't going to do anything. To open the modal:

```
$('#ModalZK').modal('show');
```

See [their documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods) for more details. When in doubt about what JavaScript is doing, run it in your browser's console first. If you had run your line in Chrome, you would have seen some HTML, indicating that it found the element, but it won't do anything because you called no function on it.

Working example:

```js
$('.ShowBtn').click(function() {
  $('#ModalZK').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<button type="button" class="ShowBtn">Show modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="ModalZK" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only"></span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel4" style="text-align:center ">Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
```

Comment: The line in VB said that the script has to be a string so I made it like this with modal and show:             Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "none", "$('#ModalZK').modal('show');") but still no pop up from code behind. Is RegisterStartupScript correct?

Comment: Oh and I just think about as Javascript I have (only) Jquery installed, maybe this is an issue?

Comment: @Henk Yes that's an issue, you need to reference Bootstrap's JavaScript library too. Look at my code snippet in the answer.

Comment: NoScript in Firefox warns not to do that. My js is/was after Form and before the end of Body: <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></scr

Comment: @Henk It warns you not to do what? You need to be specific. And are you getting any client side JavaScript errors? Are you loading all files properly?

Comment: There are no errors mason, just no respond. I don't need a button. Just edited my question.

Comment: @Henk I put the button on there so you can run the JavaScript here and verify that it's working. And changing your question is *not cool*, because  that invalidates existing answers.

Comment: Please think about your problem logically: verify that you 1) have jQuery and Bootstrap JavaScript files, and Bootstrap CSS referenced properly in your HTML 2) Verify that all files are being pulled down by your JavaScript properly 3) Run `$('#ModalZK').modal('show');` in your browser's JS console 4) Verify you have no JavaScript answers. If you do that and it works, that means your problem is with your VB.NET code. And there shouldn't be, assuming you used the code shown in your question.

Comment: About the bootstrap Javascript that was added anyway: It was already late here: midnight. The only difference I see is that I have the css in the head section and the js in the body section.

Comment: Is your VB.NET code running? What happens if you do `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "none", "alert('Hi');", True)`?

Comment: The code in my question caused a problem in I.E., not in Firefox, so I changed it to the code you provide, I use that now. Will test your reply in an hour, must go eat now.

Comment: @ mason 2) I don't understand what you mean 3) I don't know where that is, have to search and spend time on it. 4) I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Henk I only had 3 points, and you started with 2. Please edit your comment to match the numbers so I can understand which part you're stuck at.

Comment: Your next question in your next message is easy to test for me and might shine light on it: In the order of         ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "none", "$('#ModalZK').modal('show');")

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "none", "alert('Hi');", True) the alert script is not executed and nothing happens with that line. Not finished yet...

Comment: @Henk That means you probably have a VB.NET issue, and you're not registering the startup script. Set a [breakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) in the code and see if it's reached.

Comment: I meant not finished explaining to you yet, wanted to test it in the opposite order. And in the opposite order the alert script is executed rightly! But still not the other script.

Comment: You really need to work on your communication skills. As a programmer, you need to learn how to communicate effectively and concisely with others. You're not being very clear with what you're trying to say. I understand that English may not be your first language, but you still have to communicate your idea fully if you expect me to be able to help you.

Comment: 1) is ok. 2,3 and 4 really see earlier message and you really have 4). Now, in the first order of the scripts in Form Load the initial script blocks the alert script and when switched the alert script comes first and is executed well. And in both cases the initial script is not executed. I like to spend time on your testing suggestions but now I go sporting.

Comment: Now I have it worked; changing the function in your example, for without a button, and not using it in Code Behind. <script>

        $("#txtSomething").focusout(function () {
            $('#ModalZK').modal('show');
        });
</script> It is a different way but I can move on with it.